# Subfigures on different pages

Tags: floats, subfloats

Does anybody know the easiest way to prevent a subfigure from going to the next page? I have 3 subfigures, 1 or 2 of which would easily fit on the previous page, but because it is in one figure, it puts all three figures on the next page.

My code is:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\subfigure[Results on MNIST fully connected]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.48]{result4_mnist_fc_s2gd.png}
}
\subfigure[Results on MNIST ConvNet]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.48]{result5_mnist_conv_s2gd.png}
}
\subfigure[Results on CIFAR-10 ConvNet]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.48]{result6_cifar10_s2gd.png}
}
\end{center}
\caption{Results for S2GD methods}
\label{fig:NN_example}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Float environments are unbreakable. You have to split up the `figure` into two or three.

Comment: Could  we have a minimal fully compilable  example that demonstrates the problem, so we can test possible solutions? By the way, use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment: the latter adds spurious vertical spacing.

Comment: Instead `scale` try to use `width`. If `width=0.32\textwidth` gives satisfactory big pictures, than you can put all three figures in one line. Otherwise you need to split them into two figures (as stated @HeikoOberdiek.

Comment: @Zarko Scaling makes sense, if the images have different widths. This ensures, that the image elements (text, line thickness, ...) are scaled with the same scaling factor.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, actually I /we don't know anything about image's size.If they are different width, than the scaling is right choice, however, I will check if is possible shrink images to size, which allow to put them in one line. If this is not acceptable, then I see only to possibilities: (i) make figure wider than text (for example with help of  `changepage` package or (ii) split figure as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions guys! Splitting the figure sucks but I guess I'll have to live with it :D